# spring mvc mock repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning spring and writing a simple spring boot application. I want to write a unit test for my controller. The controller interacts with a Repository which I want to mock for the purposes of the test. Using various tutorials and documentation I have arrived at the following:

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes={TestConfiguration.class,MyWebappApplication.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyWebappApplicationTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private MyRepository myRepositoryMock;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void contextLoads() throws Exception {


    MyEntity e1 = new MyEntity();
    e1.setId(1);
    e1.setDescription("e1");

    MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity();
    e2.setId(2);
    e2.setDescription("e2");

    when(myRepositoryMock.findAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(e1, w2));



    mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

}

My TestConfigiration that provides the mock repository:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyRepository myRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
    }

}
```

When I run the test, I don't get the mocked repository injected into the test, instead I get the real one and I get the following line in the logging output:

```
Overriding bean definition for bean 'myRepository' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=2; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=testContext; factoryMethodName=ideaRepository; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in murdoch.suppriseme.TestContext] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
```

I tried using the `@Primary` annotation on the bean to make it take precedence, but this didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve the proper instance by adhering to `@Qualifier`

so

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mock")
    public MyRepository myRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyRepository.class);
    }

}
```

and in your test

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mock")
private MyRepository myRepositoryMock;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your test is using TestConfiguration.class but your class is named TestContext?